# Importing Javascript module in Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, javascript, firefox-addon-bootstrap

I am developing a simple Firefox extension but am having trouble importing my custom Javascript module file. The `bootstrap.js` file is at the root and `test.jsm` is inside the `content` folder.
`test.jsm` exports 2 symbols `foo` and `bar` as:

```
this.EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["foo", "bar"];
```

As per the [Using JavaScript code modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using) article, I already have a `content` instruction in the `chrome.manifest` file:

```
content     myaddon   content/
```

So, I should be able to import `test.jsm` into `bootstrap.js` as:

```
 Components.utils.import("chrome://myaddon/content/test.jsm");
```

But I see the following 2 warnings in the Browser Console:

```
addons.xpi
WARN
Error loading bootstrap.js for myaddon@oyenamit: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIXPCComponents_Utils.import]"
nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"
location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm ->
jar:file:///Users/oyenamit/Library/Application%20Support/Firefox/Profiles/profilename/extensions/myaddon@oyenamit.xpi!/bootstrap.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 1"
data: no] Stack trace: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm ->
jar:file:///Users/oyenamit/Library/Application%20Support/Firefox/Profiles/profilename/extensions/myaddon@oyenamit.xpi!/bootstrap.js:1
< resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:4348
< XPI_loadBootstrapScope()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:4348
< XPI_callBootstrapMethod()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:4423
< AI_startInstall/<()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:5849
< next()@self-hosted:675 < TaskImpl_run()@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:330
< Handler.prototype.process()@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm ->
resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:867 <
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop()@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm ->
resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:746 <
this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<()@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm ->
resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:688 < <file:unknown>




addons.xpi
WARN
Exception running bootstrap method startup on myaddon@oyenamit: ReferenceError: foo is not defined (resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm ->
jar:file:///Users/oyenamit/Library/Application%20Support/Firefox/Profiles/profilename/extensions/myaddon@oyenamit.xpi!/bootstrap.js:16:4) JS Stack trace:
startup@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm ->
jar:file:///Users/oyenamit/Library/Application%20Support/Firefox/Profiles/profilename/extensions/myaddon@bootstrap.js:16:5 <
XPI_callBootstrapMethod@XPIProvider.jsm:4451:9 <
AI_startInstall/<@XPIProvider.jsm:5864:13
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using Firefox 39.0.

A sample XPI file can be downloaded from [here](http://d.pr/f/9tX1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom JSM modules need to be imported in the `startup` function of your bootstrap.js file, i dont know why this is, but it just works like that. It wont work if you import it at the top of your file.

Be sure to unload it it on shutdown, this is a very simple demo and guide on how to do it:

https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9045387#file-bootstrap-js-L6

Comment: I found that one consequence of calling the JSM module from `bootstrap.js` is that the JSM does not have direct access to constants like `ADDON_ENABLE`. We need to pass them from `bootstrap.js`.

Comment: That's true @oyenamit

Comment: Note that this method is not for the newer WebExtensions format.